# how does jboss load the lnk like http://localhost:8088/plant/app/?

Tags: java, jboss, war

I started a jboss (6.x) locally, and can load the app with the lnk
http://localhost:8088/plant/app/
There is war deployed under standalone/deployments/ as plant.war. So, I know the element of "plant" in the lnk refers to this war deployment. However, there is no sub-folder in the war. So, how is "app" is parsed?